# arithmetic on const generics in rust

Tags: rust, const-generics

Consider the following two examples:

```rust
struct Polynomial<const DEGREE: usize> {
    factors: [isize; DEGREE + 1],
}

struct GenericSudoku<const SIZE: usize> {
    board: [[Option<usize>; SIZE.pow(2)]; SIZE.pow(2)],
}
```

These don't compile because of arithmetic operations on const generics ([as decribed here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/generics.html)).

It would however, be very convenient to have const generics that are derived from, but not equal to, other const generics.

Is there some other way to achieve this?

Comment: I recently had a related issue. The required feature is not yet stable but available on nightly. I managed to get at lest the sudoku example to compile: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=56918f13a46cb509ecf19c0944bea3c1

Comment: Only on nightly.

Comment: @RichardNeumann Thanks! Unfortunately I have come to the conclusion that the feature is still a bit too experimental to be used, but I'm happy it's being worked on. Seemed like such an obvious missing feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it on nightly, with [`#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/76560), or if you feel brave, with [`typenum`](https://docs.rs/typenum) and [`generic-array`](https://docs.rs/generic-array):

```rust
use std::ops::{Add, Mul};

use generic_array::{ArrayLength, GenericArray};
use typenum::{op, U1};

struct Polynomial<Degree>
where
    Degree: Add<U1>,
    <Degree as Add<U1>>::Output: ArrayLength,
{
    factors: GenericArray<isize, op!(Degree + U1)>,
}

struct GenericSudoku<Size>
where
    Size: Mul,
    <Size as Mul>::Output: ArrayLength,
{
    board: GenericArray<GenericArray<Option<usize>, op!(sqr(Size))>, op!(sqr(Size))>,
}

type FourthDegreePolynomial = Polynomial<typenum::U4>;
type VeryLargeSudoku = GenericSudoku<typenum::U100>;
```

As you can see, it can get very unwieldy quickly.

Comment: Thanks! I agree with you on the unwieldy part. I think this feature needs to mature a bit before I'll be confident using it.